# Eclipse Juno spell checker refuses to ignore email address in Javadoc @author field

Tags: eclipse

I have @author Javadoc tags in class comments. Frustratingly, the Eclipse Juno spell checker, an otherwise very helpful tool, keeps insisting that the email address is misspelled, as shown below:

[image: spell check error in email address]

The Spelling option 'Ignore internet addresses' is checked. Adding '@healthometry.com' to a User Defined Dictionary doesn't help - the spell checker keeps insisting there is a spelling error, '@healthometry.com', in the address.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "@" is reserved for tags in JavaDoc, so your mail address is simply not valid there. Use the HTML sequence "& # 064;" (without the blanks) instead.

Comment: +1 Changed my @author tags to `@author Boris Brudnoy &lt;boris.brudnoy&#064;healthometry.com&gt;`. Haven't realized it before but in addition to the `@` char the `<>` were receiving special handling as well and so my email address wouldn't even **appear** in the generated docs. It's there now and the spell checker is placated too.